# Android Studio strange UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: android, libvlc

After got success on compiling my to **libvcl.so** for arm64-v8a and x86_64 **in release mode** under Ubuntu, and then moved in my Android Studio project adding in build.gradle:

```
android {
    namespace 'myproject
    compileSdk 34

    androidResources {
        generateLocaleConfig true
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "myproject"
        minSdk 26
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 5
        versionName '2.3'
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }
    buildToolsVersion '34.0.0'

    sourceSets {
        main {
            //jniLibs.srcDir('src/main/jniLibs')
        }
    }

    splits {
        abi {
            enable true
            reset()
            include "x86_64" , "arm64-v8a"
            universalApk false
        }
    }

}

ext.abiCodes = [x86_64:1, 'arm64-v8a':2]
```

and adding in MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    static {
        //System.loadLibrary("c++_shared");
        //System.loadLibrary("vlcjni");
        System.loadLibrary("vlc");
    }
   .
   .
   .
}
```

and inserting in the requested .java file :

```
import org.videolan.libvlc.LibVLC;
import org.videolan.libvlc.Media;
import org.videolan.libvlc.MediaPlayer;
import org.videolan.libvlc.util.VLCVideoLayout;
```

and so on...then putting .so libraries just under *jniLibs/arm64-v8a* and *jniLibs/x86_64* .

If I compile directly in debug mode to the mobile phone , it works at all. Even if I disconnect the mobile phone from the PC and start the app itself it works and I can play audio and video, totally happy.

But if I generate APK as release, then if I call the page that should initialize the libvlc , it crashes with this error:

```
FindClass(org/videolan/libvlc/interfaces/IMedia$Slave) failed
Can't load vlcjni library: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: JNI_ERR returned from JNI_OnLoad in "/data/app/~~DKbqsxDrx0Jyd0652P5lhg==/........-IgwGtHhM5vTdQLwyhcry4w==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a/libvlcjni.so"
```

do you all know if it would be related to the Ubuntu compilation around linking maybe?
Or maybe it needs some certain parameters in Android Studio when I am building in release mode?
Because if on debug mode, it works and in release mode no, it makes me thinking in debug mode Android Studio inserts some link to libvlcjni.so (**which is present in the directory**), instead it doesn't in release mode so it crashes...
Thanks to all in advance!

Cheers

Comment: Disable minifyEnabled/proguard for the release and try again.

Comment: HI @Robert , disabling the minifyEnabled did the trick , thank you a lot! But I wonder why it would mess everythin, because minifying would just save some space. I assume....-

Comment: Saving space means removing something. It is normal that you have to manually tweak Proguard using it's config file to not remove essential files, classes, methods... The ability of Proguard to detect what is required and what not is pretty low.